# Get ProgressBar to fill StatusBarItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar, statusbar

I have a `StatusBar` that I'd like to house a `TextBlock` docked to the left and a `ProgressBar` filling the remaining width. In all my other experiences with the WPF `ProgressBar`, it will fill its given container, however in this situation it doesn't auto-size at all, it just appears as a tiny circle. Setting its height and width manually work fine, but I'd like it to scale to the remaining width of the `StatusBar`.

Here's my XAML for the `StatusBar`:

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="25">
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblStatus"  Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbStatus" />
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just need one extra attribute: `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the StatusBarItem.  Thus:

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="25">
  <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblStatus" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
  </StatusBarItem>
  <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">  <!-- Note extra attribute -->
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbStatus" />
  </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```