# WPF ProgressBar in StatusBar won't stretch

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, statusbar

New to WPF & I have the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.RossKiosk.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <StatusBar Name="StatusBarMain" Height="30"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockStatus" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBarMain" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="15" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInfo" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>

    <Grid Name="GridMain">

        <!-- Dynamically Created buttons -->


    </Grid>


</DockPanel>
```

I want the ProgressBar to fill the centre portion of the StatusBar but it only shows itself a few pixels in width. Any ideas?

Comment: try to wrap all your statusbaritems into a grid and see if it works.

Comment: This helped me, but I needed to add Grid Row and Column Definitions to make it work properly.<p>
<pre><code>
&lt;Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" ToolTip="abc213"&gt;
              &lt;Grid.RowDefinitions&gt;
                &lt;RowDefinition Height="Auto"&gt;&lt;/RowDefinition&gt;
                &lt;RowDefinition Height="*"&gt;&lt;/RowDefinition&gt;
            &lt;/Grid.RowDefinitions&gt;
                &lt;Grid.ColumnDefinitions&gt;
                    &lt;ColumnDefinition Width="*"&gt;&lt;/ColumnDefinition&gt;
</pre></code>
</p>

Comment: I am having trouble formatting my answer. please disregard

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068601/get-progressbar-to-fill-statusbaritem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to `StatusBar` using a `DockPanel` to lay out its children by default. Please see my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373529/how-do-i-customize-the-wpf-statusbar-layout/1373531#1373531).

Answer (score 7):

You will need to use a Grid. A DockPanel or StackPanel will not suffice for you.
Try:

```
    <Grid>
    <StatusBar Name="StatusBarMain" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockStatus" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBarMain" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="15" />
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInfo" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" />
    </StatusBarItem>
   </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: downvote reason: grid should be wrapped within <StatusBar>, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, but I needed to add Grid Row and Column Definitions to make it work properly.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" ToolTip="abc213">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" for `<StatusBarItem>` and it has helped:

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="5" Visibility="Visible" Name="CProgressBar" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

Answer (score -2):

This stretches the progress bar to its container

```
<StatusBarItem  Name="progressBarContainer">
    <ProgressBar Height="{Binding ElementName=progressBarContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=progressBarContainer, Path=ActualWidth}" Value="50" />
</StatusBarItem>
```